# Why do we care about locally compact abelian groups in probability theory?

Tags: probability, soft-question

I know $\mathbb{R,Z}$ under addition are locally compact abelian groups but in what context does the additional generality of the locally compact abelian group become useful to probability theorists? I have seen many results for that case, but I am unaware of the motivation for such works. Can someone provide an explanation or a reference to an exposition if it already exists?

Comment: I would guess that local compactness is important for local integrability, since that's core to much of probability

Comment: Not an expert at all, but basically LC groups admits translation invariant measures [maybe Haar measure], which is of much usage for developing a good theory [I am just simply rambling here ;)]